# Xcode 9 Swift 4 AR app add ads

Tags: ios, ads, xcode9

I am trying to add iads to my Xcode9/Swift 4 AR project.

From searching online, adding iads to the viewcontroller should be as easy as dragging the iad banner view into the main.storyboard, however there doesn't seem to be any options for ads in Xcode 9. Is this something with the new Xcode version? Or do I need to install some sort of add plugin to use iads. If for some reason iads got removed from Xcode I could always fall back on adMob for IOS.

Thanks, any info helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, iAds have been depreciated. There are multiple in-app ad services which you can use, one of the most popular ones is, as you mentioned, AdMobs.

You would need to create an AdMob account, and install the [Google AdMobs SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start), which is easily done through terminal/CocoaPods.

To create ads you need to first create an Ad Unit, after you've signed up to AdMobs.

Once you have done that, use [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner) documentation, depending on the type of ad(s) you wish to display, to invoke and display ads. Keep in mind, different ads which require different delegates/methods.

But in regards to your question, you are not wrong nor is there any issues. Simple iAds have been abandoned, in essence.

Answer (score 0):

iAd App Network got shut down at the end of 2016. You should use adMob as you stated, or some other form of ads for your app.